# Перестройка хэш-таблицы, когда среднее количество элементов, хранимых в одном слоте (bucket) превосходит пороговое значение

Tags: php, java, c++, python, хеширование

Два примера и вопрос.

Пример на PHP:

```
<?php

$table = array();
$info = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 65535; $i++) $table[$i] = '';

for ($i = 65535; $i < 65538; $i++) {
    $t = microtime(true);
    $table[$i] = '';
    $t = microtime(true) - $t;
    $info[] = array($i, $t);
}

for ($i = 65538; $i < 131071; $i++) $table[$i] = '';

for ($i = 131071; $i < 131074; $i++) {
    $t = microtime(true);
    $table[$i] = '';
    $t = microtime(true) - $t;
    $info[] = array($i, $t);
}

?><pre><?php print_r($info) ?></pre>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65535
            [1] => 5.0067901611328E-6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65536
            [1] => 0.0043141841888428
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65537
            [1] => 9.5367431640625E-7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 131071
            [1] => 3.0994415283203E-6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 131072
            [1] => 0.0083508491516113
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 131073
            [1] => 9.5367431640625E-7
        )

)
```

Пример на Python:

```
from time import time
from pprint import pprint

table = {}
info = []

for i in range(0, 21844):
    table[i] = ''

for i in range(21844, 21847):
    t = time()
    table[i] = ''
    t = time() - t
    info.append((i, t))

for i in range(21847, 87380):
    table[i] = ''

for i in range(87380, 87383):
    t = time()
    table[i] = ''
    t = time() - t
    info.append((i, t))

pprint(info)
```

Результат:

```
[(21844, 9.5367431640625e-07),
 (21845, 0.0022368431091308594),
 (21846, 9.5367431640625e-07),
 (87380, 2.1457672119140625e-06),
 (87381, 0.0048618316650390625),
 (87382, 1.9073486328125e-06)]
```

Вроде бы, как я понимаю, сложность вставки элемента с учетом переформирования таблицы все еще остается O(1), но если каким-то образом озвучить интерпретатору заранее, на какое максимальное количество ключей в таблице я рассчитываю, то можно существенно уменьшить константу перед O, а так же избежать многих резервирований памяти.

Как я понял, PHP и Python "из коробки" этого не умеют.

**Вопрос такой: какие скриптовые языки это умеют?** Исключения: подойдут ответы на C++ и Java, а также пояснения, почему это вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Язык **perl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

my $start=time(); ### Сохраняем время старта

my @a;  ### Объявляем пустой массив

### Раскоментарить следующие 3 строки для второй части теста:
# my $t=time();
# $#a=200000;  ### Вот тут резервируем 200k элементов ($#a - количество элементов массива @a)
# print "Reservation: ",time()-$t,"\n";

for(my $i=0;$i<200000;$i++) {
 my $t=time();
 $a[$i]=$i;
 my $r=time()-$t;
 print "$i: $r\n" if( $r > 9e-5 );  ### Лимит времени подобрать под вашу машину
}

print "Run time is ", time()-$start, "\n";
```

Вывод программы с закоментаренными строками резервирования памяти:

```
8190: 0.000108003616333008
16382: 0.000221967697143555
32766: 0.000423908233642578
65534: 0.00084996223449707
131070: 0.00179505348205566
Run time is 0.421634912490845
```

При многократном запуске, провалы в скорости операции выделения очередного элемента остаются стабильно на тех же элементах массива.

А теперь раскоментарим строки перед циклом, суть которых просто изменить количество элементов в существующем массиве (`$#a=200000;`), результат выполнения:

```
Reservation: 0.00147509574890137
Run time is 0.407889842987061
```

Заметно, что без предварительного резервирования памяти "провальное" время добавления элемента при необходимости реорганизации массива, нарастает с его размером. И что важно, время реорганизации на элементе 131070 сравнимо с временем резервирования памяти под 200k элементов. А общее время выполнения программы с резервированием меньше, чем без него. Так что польза на лицо.

**UPD**:

Правда это был именно массив, хеши в perl это другие структуры. Но и в них можно кое что сделать для оптимизации. Поменяем в программе массив на хеш, для этого объявление `my @a` меняем на `my %a`, обращение к элементу `$a[$i]` меняем на `$a{$i}`. Резервирование количества buckets для хеша выполняется с помощью `keys(%a)=200000;` (Надо заметить, что фактически резервируется 262144, т.е. степень 2 buckets, проверяется как `$a{1}=1; keys(%a)=200000; print scalar(%a);` результат: `1/262144`). Результаты любопытные ...

Без резервирования:

```
3401: 0.000152826309204102
4095: 0.000200033187866211
7497: 0.000319957733154297
8192: 0.00032496452331543
15689: 0.000678062438964844
16384: 0.000677824020385742
32074: 0.00168180465698242
32769: 0.00153708457946777
64841: 0.00349617004394531
65535: 0.00367498397827148
130379: 0.00778102874755859
130453: 0.000139951705932617
131074: 0.00826096534729004
174142: 0.000139951705932617
Run time is 0.533354043960571
```

С резервированием:

```
Reservation: 0.0016169548034668
3401: 0.000159978866577148
7497: 0.000318050384521484
15689: 0.000644922256469727
32074: 0.00147390365600586
64841: 0.00345706939697266
130379: 0.00780797004699707
130433: 0.000134944915771484
Run time is 0.531057119369507
```

Т.е. провалы скорости выполнения операции заметны, но на меньшем количестве элементов. Природа такого поведения мне не известна.

Comment: Аж полез смотреть исходники :) С [массивами](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/av.c) вроде всё просто. Ресайз  лёгкий, и условия его возникновения понятны. Прирост скорости есть, то не такой чтобы уж совсем (у меня `0.14478588104248` vs `0.137899875640869` при 200_000 элементах, и `1.10408186912537` vs `1.04192900657654` при 2_000_000). А вот с [хэшами](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/hv.c)  сложней. По идее ресайз должен идти при превышении размера какой-то корзины (а может и не одной), но так ли это на самом деле надо вникать. И ясно, что это сильно зависит от входных данных.

Comment: @PinkTux, среднее количество элементов в букете, как я понял, вычисляется одинаково во всех реализациях. Количество элементов (инкремент/декремент при добавлении/удалении элемента) разделить на количество букетов. Вопрос именно в том, чтобы можно было хешу заранее задать количество ключей, которое не будет превзойдено. И почему этого нельзя сделать практически во всех популярных скриптовых языках. Если это можно сделать на крестах, то такой ответ тоже будет с моей точки зрения хорошим.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov , не уверен про все реализации. На хабре мелькала статья про [хэши в PHP7](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/308240/). От перловых они точно отличаются. Что же касается количества ключей, то мы всё равно не можем ни соблюсти соотношение одно место->одно значение, ни предсказать распределение значений по корзинам. Во всяком случае во многих сишных реализациях (моей самопальной в том числе) можно задавать  начальное количество корзин, а не элементов хэша.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Почему нельзя ... вы видите выигрыш мал, наверняка зависит не только от количества ключей но и главное от распределения даваемого хеш функцией и для любой функции могут найтись данные, которые все равно нарушат равномерность распределения. А подавляющее число пишушщих на этих языках о производительности не задумываются и для кого тогда делать этот функционал